# customer expense query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, select

Need to build a query showing how much customers spend money per week, month, quarter, 6 months and a year on a daily on-line game. There is a field create date(datetime) field when one customer enters the game.

Can anyone help?

Comment: You will have to provide more details on your schema/database for someone to help you a bit better, but you are looking for aggregate functions here, something like: SELECT WEEK(e.CreateDate) Week, SUM(Expenditure) WeeksExpenditure FROM Expenditure e WHERE YEAR(e.CreateDate) = 2011 GROUP BY WEEK(e.CreateDate). Please note this is pseudocode as there is no DB listed and the date functions tend to differ

Comment: well im using SQL Server 2008...And it says there is no built in Week Function...The thing is I just need a idea to found those customers expense in different intervals in same query...Note that customers are irregular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps something like this.

```
declare @T table (CreatedDate datetime, MoneySpent int)

insert into @T values
('20101231', 5),
('20100101', 10),
('20100102', 20),
('20100103', 30),
('20110104', 40),
('20110105', 50),
('20110106', 60),
('20110107', 70)

-- per year
select
  sum(MoneySpent) Spent,
  year(CreatedDate) [Year]
from @T
group by year(CreatedDate)

-- per month
select
  sum(MoneySpent) Spent,
  year(CreatedDate) [Year],
  month(CreatedDate) [Month]
from @T
group by year(CreatedDate), month(CreatedDate)

-- per half year
select
  sum(MoneySpent) Spent,
  year(CreatedDate) [Year],
  case when month(CreatedDate) <= 6 then 'First' else 'Second' end [HalfYear]
from @T
group by year(CreatedDate), case when month(CreatedDate) <= 6 then 'First' else 'Second' end

-- per quarter
select
  sum(MoneySpent) Spent,
  year(CreatedDate) [Year],
  ((month(CreatedDate)-1) % 4)+1 [Quarter]
from @T
group by year(CreatedDate), ((month(CreatedDate)-1) % 4)+1

-- per week
select
  sum(MoneySpent) Spent,
  year(CreatedDate) [Year],
  datepart(iso_week, CreatedDate) [Week]
from @T
group by year(CreatedDate), datepart(iso_week, CreatedDate)
```

Result

```
Spent       Year
----------- -----------
65          2010
220         2011

Spent       Year        Month
----------- ----------- -----------
60          2010        1
220         2011        1
5           2010        12

Spent       Year        HalfYear
----------- ----------- --------
60          2010        First
220         2011        First
5           2010        Second

Spent       Year        Quarter
----------- ----------- -----------
60          2010        1
220         2011        1
5           2010        4

Spent       Year        Week
----------- ----------- -----------
220         2011        1
5           2010        52
60          2010        53
```